# the ring of formal power series over $F$ with the variable

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

i have little knowledge on Field theory, but not ring theory,i am now reading peper in wireless communication and i have found definition and it look for me like Japanese language  and it difficult form and i haven't the power to writes so i have take picture,

[image]
[image]

Can any one explane the mathematical term in this definition an if it possible with example please help me

[image]

Comment: any think to close me to understand the definition,please thanks.or give some good pdf about ring  with examples

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: Linear Network coding

Comment: Also, which is the first term that you don't understand?

Comment: Linear Network Coding -- is that a book, or an article? Who is the author?

Comment: i have put the picture contain the name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62614/discussion-between-mokh-tar-bou-and-quasi).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it was a book, but thanks for showing the source.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{C}$ is a **free** module of rank $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ ? This means nothing more than $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \implies \alpha = a+ib$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and the multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $i^2 = -1$. Thus $(1,i)$ is a basis for this free module. In general you can have **free** modules over (an integral domain) $S$ of large rank $n$, and you can think to its basis as matrices $n \times n$ with coefficients in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

The formal power series, as a set, is the same as the set of sequences with values in $F$.

The sum of elements is component-wise. But the multiplication is defined as

$(a_0,a_1,...)\cdot(b_0,b_1,...) = (c_0,c_1,...)$

with $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$.

Normally, to make the multiplication familiar people write the sequences with powers of a variable:

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$$

with these operations it is a ring where $(0,0,...)$ is the zero and $(1,0,0,...)$ is the multiplicative neutral.

Comment: Nice first post! Welcome to MSE.

Comment: as i said befor i dont know so much in field theory

Comment: @MokhTarBou Fields allow addition, subtraction, multiplication and division by non-zero elements. Think of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or $\{0,1,...,p\}$ with $p$ prime and operations mod $p$.

Comment: You didn't explain the (free ?) module part.

Comment: good morning caone help men any